# Complex QR validation UX. Validate 1 entry or group?

Tags: usability, mobile, android, validation, iphone

I've been trying to find a solution to speed up the validation of the QR for tickets.

The thing is that in the industry the people validating the tickets are used to sounds, like beep for "OK" or beep beep for "WRONG" but I was trying to make the process quicker so that whenever the app detects multiple tickets in one transaction, they let the assistant at the door to choose between the whole group or just one person. This is not the best solution because sometimes there's in a transaction of 5, they go 4 and the assistant gets confused and doesn't know very well what to do. The common sense would be to click 1, then another till 4, but sometimes they tend to click on 5.

So I wasn't able to solve the problem yet. I thought about the possibility to put like a draggable input, but is not that quick, but maybe more intuitive. Or just  forget about the group validation or change the text to (everyone here?)

Any good idea please?

[image: This is how it looks like at the moment]

Comment: Who's the "they" in the industry? And what "sound" would they hear? Do you mean a bouncer verbally expressing themselves? When you talk about making the process quicker, can you explain where you're currently observing friction?

Comment: Have you tried the options of "This Ticket" and "All Tickets" vs. using numbers?

Comment: @RoAchterberg thanks for your reply, I've added some info in the description solving your answers. About friction if there's no multiple QR validation, then the people validating tickets takes some seconds validating each QR, that's why I wanted to speed it up by adding an option to validate the whole group, but the problem is that the actual solution confuses when the group is incomplete. I've seen some apps adding a link to select the linked tickets one by one, but it's the same as validating the QR itself, same time and no improvement.

Comment: @RoAchterberg I was thinking for example dragging a button and while dragging some numbers will appear and you drop the correct one

Comment: @Izquierdo didn't like that because the person validating needs to know the numbers to let the correct number of people geting inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the usual case is whole parties entering together, and people entering with incomplete parties are an edge case.

[image: Two screens showing a ticket entry system that allows the user to enter number of adults and children easily]

In your example, it appears that there are 5 tickets sold at 2 option levels. Option 1 allows 2 people to enter, and Option 2 allows 3 people to enter. During this process, it's probably important to know how many remaining entrants are allowed for each option so that you don't have entrants potentially sneaking into higher-paying levels.

In my example above, let's assume that two teachers are taking 24 children to the movies. Adults can be Option 1, and Children under 12 can be option 2.

Because "all parties entering together" is the usual case (example on the left), you app would default to 2 adults and 24 children. If the ticket-taker needs to modify those numbers, they can either tap the box to enter a value, or use the plus and minus buttons to add or remove an entrant, one-at-a-time.

Let's assume that one teacher is not with the party, and needs to enter later (example on the right). They'll show the app, and now the ticket-taker can enter up to one adult. Since all of the children have been admitted, there is no longer an option to select them.

An Admit button at the bottom helps the user confirm that the values are correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, at the end, after thinking so much, you came up with a simple solution which I like. The only thing is that in the main view, I've put a link to this view, because it's for "advanced" users as usually what assistants understand is 1 QR, 1 attendee. BTW do you have a web, linkedin or place to be contacted?

Comment: Sure, see my profile for my Twitter handle. My LinkedIn is under the same name.

Answer (score 2):

I think (but it's an assumption I make) that the assistants like to count the people that enter. So based on the information you gave I would add a counter. Big buttons and not too many options are key for the situations that the assistants are in. But I would also add the possibility to choose all at once. Something like this:

[image]

<sub>Maybe not the best design, but I hope it serves its purpose as an example.</sub>

The "All" button should change the number to the max making it possible to count down, in this example from 5 to 4 etc. making usage a bit quicker. You mentioned how assistants make mistakes: A confirm button adds the opportunity to review the choice made, hopefully reducing the amount of mistakes.

Comment: Nice answer! I like the ability to tap the plus button as a counter.

Comment: @jazZRo Thank you very much, at the end I liked more the other solution, but your's it's very much in the line of what I have in mind to solve the problem. But of course up voted! Is there any place to see your work, linkedin or any contact place?